# import options in radio button Magento

Tags: magento, import

I have a site with Magento 1.7 
I have create a custom import for my client but if I write this in the csv in the place of the options

```
CIANO:fixed:0:EP10-CHIP9700C:0|MAGENTA:fixed:0:EP10-CHIP9700VM:0|GIALLO:fixed:0:EP10-CHIP9700Y:0|NERO MATTE:fixed:0:EP10-CHIP9700MB:0|
```

It create options in a dropdown.

This is the filed that create in csv:
A column:

```
Capacit :drop_down:0:0
```

And a column

```
Colore:drop_down:0:0
```

In this mode in this column it put the options but if I have radio and dropdown?
Have I to create other column nearby like:

```
Capacit : radio:0:0
```

Or which mode?

How can I pass into the csv a value that indicate that this options are a radiobutton? 
Thanks

Comment: that you will have to code in script and not in csv

Comment: But in this line you can specify if is in a dropdown or not I thinked and I have seen in some link but not with radio options @KalpeshMehta

Comment: then you may try to check in code how it handles CSV file. From there you might get an idea what is the condition for radio buttons.

Comment: I have edit with the csv that is created the probloemi is that the file create a column dropdown, I have to add the column radio and in the import decide in whic column i have to put the options?